# Android SQLite Only get the latest result in Looping (ArrayList,HashMap)

Tags: android, json, sqlite, arraylist, hashmap

i have a problem while fetching data from db and iterating `arrayList`, for example, i inserted two data in sqlite and i want to select by using looping. but i only selected last row data in my looping. any suggestion to solve this problem

```
public void postDataDtl(String DocNo) {
        database = new ProductDatabase.ProductDatabaseHelper(activityContext);
        try{
            String selectQuery = "select * from BarcodeDtl where DocNo='"+DocNo+"'";
            SQLiteDatabase db1 = database.getWritableDatabase();
            cursor =db1.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Barlist = new ArrayList<>();
        hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        data = new JSONObject();
        array = new JSONArray();
        while(cursor.isAfterLast()==false) {
            branch = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Branch"));
            docno = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DocNo"));
            time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Time"));
            seqno = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("SeqNo"));
            barcode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Barcode"));
            qty = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Quantity"));

            hashMap.put("branch",branch);
            hashMap.put("docno",docno);
            hashMap.put("time",time);
            hashMap.put("seqno",seqno);
            hashMap.put("barcode",barcode);
            hashMap.put("qty",qty);
            Barlist.add(hashMap);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
//the problem is this for loop getting same result
        for(int i=0; i<Barlist.size();i++) {
            data.put("Branch", hashMap.get("branch"));
            data.put("DocNo", hashMap.get("docno"));
            data.put("CTime", hashMap.get("time"));
            data.put("Seq", hashMap.get("seq"));
            data.put("Barcode", hashMap.get("barcode"));
            data.put("Qty", hashMap.get("qty"));
            array.put(data);
        }
//            }

//                array.put(data);
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: cursor =db1.rawQuery(selectQuery, null); what you get in cursor? two data or one?

Comment: @ZakiPathan i selected two data

Comment: and my Barlist.size() also count as two

Comment: this is confusing. for(int i=0; i<Barlist.size();i++) {
            data.put("Branch", hashMap.get("branch"));
            data.put("DocNo", hashMap.get("docno"));
            data.put("CTime", hashMap.get("time"));
            data.put("Seq", hashMap.get("seq"));
            data.put("Barcode", hashMap.get("barcode"));
            data.put("Qty", hashMap.get("qty"));
            array.put(data);
        }  why u get value from hashMap? what your hashMap have? 2 data or single data?

Comment: my hashMap get two data , but it get the latest data and duplicate

Comment: @AnthonyTang try with below answer you will find out the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your mistake

Move your `hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); into while loop`

and then

```
for(int i=0; i<Barlist.size();i++) {
        HashMap hashMap = Barlist.get(i);   // you have to get hashMap from Barlist again.
        data.put("Branch", hashMap.get("branch"));
        data.put("DocNo", hashMap.get("docno"));
        data.put("CTime", hashMap.get("time"));
        data.put("Seq", hashMap.get("seq"));
        data.put("Barcode", hashMap.get("barcode"));
        data.put("Qty", hashMap.get("qty"));
        array.put(data);
    }
```

Comment: sorry for disturb again, 1 more question, String entity = new StringEntity(array.toString());  httppost.setEntity(entity);

Comment: this is how i call the array in Entity, but i'm still getting both same result in array, do you know about this?

Comment: this means your data is same. First make it confirm that your database stores 2 different row_data. Then the way you are actually adding data to to hashMap and then to ArrayList. At last parsing arrayList data and adding to JSONObject and JSONObject to JSONArray.

Comment: if you need the JSONArray then why are you mixing the whole code. Simply add data to JSONArray from your cursor using JSONObject.

Comment: oh u are right!! I'm try to do following your instruction, thanks!!

Comment: Sir, i'm follow your instruction and it working well, but in my entity to get my JSONArray still getting same result.

Comment: can you check your curser data, means your db rows data is same or different?

Comment: ya my db confirm rows data is different, but i'm getting this >>>>[{"docno":"10001","barcode":"868-15080322\r","branch":"Batu Pahat","qty":"1","seqno":"10001","time":"2017-02-16 12:18:14"},{"docno":"10001","barcode":"868-15080322\r","branch":"Batu Pahat","qty":"1","seqno":"10001","time":"2017-02-16 12:18:14"}]>>>both is same

Comment: post your recent code as an answer in this post. do not update in question.

Comment: Sir, i'm not sure izzit i'm see wrong or what, when i try again just now, there is no insert any row into web service.

Comment: your jsonArray has data from sqlLiteDb?

Comment: my JsonArray got data from sqlitedb

Comment: then this is your server request error, which may not be able to update you the data.

Comment: my server side all work nicely also, but dont know why, nothing error appear.....

Answer (score 0):

Move your `hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();` into while loop